# How to get time of last commit date for Git repository files via Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitpython

I'm trying to get the latest commit date for each file in a specific folder in a repo.

My code:

```
import git
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

repo = git.Repo(dir_path)
tree = repo.tree()


for blob in tree.trees[1]:
    print(blob.name)
    # print(blob.path)
    commit = repo.iter_commits(paths=blob.name, max_count=100).next()
    print(commit.committed_date)
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Coding\Temp\get_commit_date.py", line 12, in <module>
    commit = repo.iter_commits(paths=blob.name, max_count=1).next()
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Is there any way to make this code work?

Comment: `commit = next(repo.iter_commits(paths=blob.name, max_count=1))`?

Comment: working absolutely file!